# Magento 2 get store id

Tags: magento2

magento 2 get store id  php

I need to show something based on store id

for exapmle;

```html
     <?php if ($store == "2") {?>
<div class="block-bottom">
      <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
       <span><?php echo __('Language'); ?></span>
      </a>
     
     </div>

<?php } else { ?>
<div class="block-bottom">
      <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
       <span><?php echo __('Language1'); ?></span>
      </a>
     
     </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [tour] and [ask]. Help us help you, show us what you tried, explain how it doesn't met your requirements and, when possible, do your best to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
if($storeId == 1){
    echo 'Store Id 1 code here';
}else{
    echo 'other stores code here';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

if ($storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId() == 1) {
    echo 'Hello';
} else {
    echo 'Thanks';
}
```

The use of object manager is not recommended. It is better to arrange this code for the class of the block using the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend injecting the StoreManagerInterface in your construct and avoid using the object manager.

Example

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;


public function __construct(Context $context,
                            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

}

public function myFunction()
{
    $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    if ($storeId == 1) {
        echo 'Store Id 1 code here';
    } else {
        echo 'other stores code here';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It didnt worked. What is wrong?

```html
<?php
$storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

if ($storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId() == 1) { ?>
   <div class="block-bottom">
      <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
       <span><?php echo __('Language'); ?></span>
      </a>
     
     </div>
<?php } else { ?>
   

     <div class="block-bottom">
      <a class="button-sticky-bottom" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-flag" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
       <span><?php echo __('Language1'); ?></span>
      </a>
     
     </div>
  <?php }
?>
```